# Is it possible to express a power series with squared coefficients as a function of the series without squared coefficients?

Tags: summation, power-series, generating-functions, nonlinear-analysis

Suppose I have two sums, $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$:

$$P(x)\equiv \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n$$

$$Q(x)\equiv \sum_{n=0}^N a_n^2 x^n$$

Is there a way to express $Q(x)$ as a function of $P(x)$?

Context: I have a nonlinear recurrence for $a_{n} \rightarrow a_{n+1}$ which includes 1st, 2nd, and 3rd powers of $a_n$.  I'd like to use $P(x)$ as a generating function for this recurrence, but I'm not sure how to express the $a_n^2$ (or $a_n^3$) sums in terms of $P(x)$, or if that's even possible.

Comment: Using complex analysis one can do this with Hadamard convolution

Comment: @Conrad Can you elaborate or post a link?  I'm not familiar with Hadamard convolution.  How does it help with this problem?

Comment: $2\pi Q(re^{it})=\int_0^{2\pi}P(re^{i(t-y)})P(e^{iy})dy, r<1$ which is called $P*P$ on the unit disc (and of course one can get a formula on any disc for polynomials); this is useful in finding asymptotic estimates for coefficients of infinite series and may be useful in this case too

Comment: Interesting.  Is there a way to do this for a sum with cubic coefficients $R(x)\equiv\sum_n a_n^3 x^n$ as well?  I guess you could express $Q$ as in your comment, then $2\pi R(re^{it}) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} P(re^{i(t-y)})Q(e^{iy})dy$ -- this seems a bit cumbersome though.

Comment: For $R=P*P*P$ we can iterate the convolution as noted in your comment - while more cumbersome, it still can be useful if you have esimates

Answer (score 1):

How about

$$Q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{P^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\right)^2 x^k$$